# When using a span with attribute role = textbox and contenteditable=true .Then copy-paste of texts inside it, doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

consider the span :

```
<span class="comment-box2" role="textbox" contentEditable=true></span>
```

with css:

```
.comment-box2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-color:#F5FFFA;
    border-radius:15px;
    border: 1px solid #708090;
    display:inline-block;
    width:330px;
}
```

When i copy plain text from a site and paste inside the span with role =textbox ,ie the above span. it creates another span inside it ,when looked through inspect element . the following line of code is seen as the inner span:

```
<span jsname="YS01Ge" style="color: rgb(32, 33, 36); font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Foot on the pedal never ever false metal</span>
```

here the "Foot on a pedal never ever false metal" is the text i copied from a site .How do i prevent the creation of the span and all of its attribute and only paste the plain text i copied onto the span with role="textbox".

In the case of just typing plain text inside the span everything works fine and no span is generated.when text is pasted it generates the above span and a white background is generated behind it which im trying to remove.

Comment: If the content to copy contains a span, it's included in the content editable element. How the clipboard works, depends on the application copying the content, and the application pasting the content. When you copy from a browser, the selected HTML elements are copied among with the plain text. When you're pasting in a browser, browser selects a suitable content depending on the paste target element.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to the attributes of the span?

Answer (score 1):

When you copy text from another website/app, the styles associated with the font are also copied. If these styles don't match, a new span is created to accommodate the new styles. The same happens in many other apps as well, for example, Excel, Word, Google sheet,etc.

Comment: No, the styles are not copied as they are, you can't paste a styled text to a (real) text editor. The tag is copied and pasted to a content editables, whereas a textarea element or a real text editor would use the saved plain text.

Comment: The styles are copied but a text editor just doesn't accepts them...if you copy it to the same platform(i.e. Web), then you would see the same styles.

Comment: Styles might be copied in RTF format, but a content editable element doesn't paste in RTF. A text editor wouldn't know what to paste, when having a tag or plain text on the clipboard. The copied information is saved to the clipboard in multiple formats, the exact formats are application dependent, ex. Excel copies a selected area even as a PNG image, you can paste it directly to a pixel graphic app. The app reading from the clipboard (executing paste) picks a format suitable to the context, and what is actually pasted varies depending on the context and the provided formats on the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your answers was really helpful for me.